# Need to create a select all button for UITableView and add selections to an array in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController that shows a list of items from NSMutableArray, along with a button that serves as a check box that the user can select/deselect.  I am able to successfully display the table, as well as the checkboxes.  However, I would like to have a tableheader at the very top of the table that would have a "select all" check box, which would allow the user to select all of the cells, or deselect all of the cells.  If some cells are already checked off, then I want only those cells that are not selected, to be selected.

Here is the code that I have thus far:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        testButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [testButton setFrame:CGRectMake(280, 57, 25, 25)];
        [testButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckBox1.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [testButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckBox2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [testButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell setAccessoryView:testButton];

    }

    // Configure the cell...
    TestObject *tObject = [[DataModel sharedInstance].testList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = tObject.testTitle;

    return cell;

}

-(void)buttonTouched:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;

    if( [[btn imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckBox1.png"]])
    {
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckBox2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        // other statements
    }
    else
    {
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckBox1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        // other statements
    }

}

//Here is the additional method that I have added to my code to select all
-(void)clickOnCheckButton {

    NSLog(@"Did it select?");

    for (int i = 0; i < [self.tableView numberOfSections]; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i]; j++) {
            NSUInteger ints[2] = {i,j};
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:ints length:2];
            UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            //Here is your code
            [self buttonTouched:nil];

        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks in advance to all who reply.

Comment: where you are facing problem. In adding checkbox in header OR in select deselect all checkbox?

Comment: Both.  How would I add a header that allows me to add "select all" button which allows me to select/deselect my selections from the table?  I have seen tutorials that show you how to add headers, but how do I add a header that includes a button that functions as described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take another `NSMUtableArray` as SelectedArray

in `didselectRowAtIndexPath` row You can Add remove objects from `SelectedArray`.

You can select a cell calling table view's `selectRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
[yourtable selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
```

Put `for loop` for `selectedArray` to putcheckbutton only in selected cells.

in Your CellForRow Method Use this

```
testButton.tag=indexpath.row;
```

you can select All row and All Section by below method.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [ptableView numberOfSections]; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < [ptableView numberOfRowsInSection:i]; j++) {
        NSUInteger ints[2] = {i,j};
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:ints length:2];
            UITableViewCell *cell = [ptableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
           //Here is your code

      UiButton *btn = (UiButton*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:j]

if( [[btn imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckBox1.png"]])
    {
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckBox2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        // other statements
    }
    else
    {
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckBox1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        // other statements
    }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt reply.  If I select all cells as you describe above, how can I add these selections to my array in didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: just assign Your selectedArray=[DataArray mutableCopy]; where DataArray is the Array for tableview data. And for Unselect All you can use [SelectedArray  removeAllObjects];
After that reload your tableview.

Comment: I added the method: -(void)clickOnCheckButton { ... } to my code above to show you what I have done, but unfortunately I am unable to select all the checkboxes in each cell.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: there is a line   `// Here is your Code` , instead of that use the code for CheckMark or button image change.

Comment: I've made the following method call:  [self buttonTouched:nil]; this method is where the code to change the image takes place, but unfortunately it is not working.  I've included the code in my original question for you to look at.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You are not passing the Button Object so its not working for you. Set Button tag in your Cell for row and Access it by tag Number. Check my updated Answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that in UITableView header than use following method:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Return UIView Object from this method which contain checkbox and what else you want.

TO check uncheck maintain an array where you can store that a checkbox is checked or not.

When user check/uncheck header change array and reload table.

Answer (score 0):

Here i m Posting Another Answer so that it might help to others who wants to make this from Scratch and remove any Confusions.

Instead of Adding Button to `tableViewCell` ,you can use ImageView as AccessoryView.

```
UIImageView *imageView1 = [[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];
imageView1.tag = indexpath.row;

[cell.accessoryView addSubview:imageView1];
```

And later get subview using -`viewWithTag`: method:

```
UIImageView *getImageView1 = (UIImageView*)[cell.accessoryView viewWithTag:rowNumber];
getImageView1.image=[UIImage ImageNamed:@"checked.png"];
```

By the Above code we can change the `image` of `imageView` in `selectRowAtindexPath`

From my first Answer you can use the code to Select all or Multiple cell of tableView.