# How to do select all function for custom cell in UITableView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode5

I have a table that imports the address book contacts and displays the image, contact name and a checkbox, i've customized my cell with image, label and a button which serves as a checkmark. I'm successfully able to display all contacts and the checkmark also works fine for individual cells, but i'm having trouble implementing select all functionality that will put all the button in the table in selected state and clicking it again will deselect it all. This is what I have done so far.

//This is the class for my custom cell

```
#import "InviteFriendsCell.h"

@implementation InviteFriendsCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

       }

   //This is my checkmark button
-(IBAction)onAddTouched:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *addButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    [addButton setSelected:![addButton isSelected]];
}
@end
```

//This is my tableview display code in FriendListViewController

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"friendsCell";

    InviteFriendsCell *cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

       if(cell==nil)
       {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"InviteFriendsCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

       }
    // Configure the cell...

    NSUInteger row = 0; 
    NSUInteger sect = indexPath.section;
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < sect; ++ i)
        row += [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i];
    row += indexPath.row;

    cell.thumbImage.layer.cornerRadius=25;
    cell.thumbImage.clipsToBounds=YES;
    cell.thumbImage.image=nil;


        self.persons = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(self.contactAdd, row);

        NSString *tweet=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",(__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyCompositeName(self.persons)] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
        [cell.friendName setText:tweet];

        if (ABPersonHasImageData(persons))
        {
            NSData  *imgData = (__bridge NSData *) ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(persons, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail);
            cell.thumbImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
        }
        else
        {
            cell.thumbImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"name_icon.png"];
        }

    return cell;
}
```

//This is my select all button which should put checkmark to all button in tableview

```
  - (IBAction)selectAll:(UIButton *)sender {

       //This is where I need to implement the code
    }
```

There is a similar question in stack overflow here [Need to create a select all button for UITableView and add selections to an array in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209145/need-to-create-a-select-all-button-for-uitableview-and-add-selections-to-an-arra)

But here the checkmark button is created inside the tableview method, my case is different and I'm unable to implement that code. Is there a better way to do this? I'm using storyboard and xcode 5 and should work for ios 5 or above.

Comment: ***Why do you write all text in bold/italic?***

Comment: It looks better that way :P

Comment: How can I downvote a comment? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first create a array with boolean values

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *selectedArray;
```

Initialise your selected array based on the contact add count, better generalise it and store it into an NSArray if u are planning to expand this. Here peopelist is my NSArray

```
self.peopleList=(__bridge NSArray *)(self.contactAdd);

           self.selectedArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:[self.peopleList count]];
           for(int i=0;i<[self.peopleList count];i++)
           {
               [self.selectedArray insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] atIndex:i];
           }

In the selectAll button action use this
- (IBAction)selectAll:(UIButton *)sender {


   for(int i=0;i<self.selectedArray.count;i++)
      [self.selectedArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:sender.isSelected]];
   [sender setSelected:!sender.isSelected];

   [yourTable reloadData];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your data source and your cell. `contactAdd` needs to know that the contact is selected (you could use a new array for this, but why would you). The cell needs to callback to the controller when the button is tapped to tell the controller about whether it's selected or not. The controller needs to update the cells to set the selected status.

Your code currently won't work properly if you have lots of cells, select some and then scroll (either other rows will show as selected or the selections will be lost depending on if your reuse identifier is configured correctly).

Also, your `contactAdd` is overly complex. Look at using multiple arrays (one per section) as your current indexing is complicated to maintain.

Comment: If i add the button programmatically in the tableview like in the link which I've provided. Would it work?

Comment: The important part is that your data model holds the selected status and the controller updates the button on the cell. The controller doesn't need to create the button (but it could).

Answer (score 0):

I really think that using predefined "selected" method is bad and rigid approach. So I would prefer the following solution:

1. Just connect touch listener to every cell and handle the Tap event. When it occurs set the cell data source "selected" and update the layout of the cell.
2. If you want to "select all" you should update all cell datasources to "selected" and then update the whole table (reloadData)

Note: instead of making one template and manipulating data you can also create two templates for the cell - selected and unselected one and implement custom template selector in your cell constructor.